# Support for Serial 64MB SPI Flash, and OpenWRT on MIPS

Tags: embedded, linux-device-driver, openwrt, device-tree, flash-memory

I have some divice this is a prototye. In device was used MCU **MT7620a**. On board I have 32 MB RAM, and 64MB SPI Flash. I whant to install OpenWRT on this device, but I have problem with correct driver to this SPI flash, because driver **m25p80** usually uses in linux handle size only to 32MB. System recognize memory as **MT25QL512AB**. So Do You have any idea what driver I have must use to good cooperation memory and MCU ?
I checked Table of Hardware available on site

http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/start

In goal find something similar, but only I found is handle max to 32MB with **m25p80**. If I found some devices for example 64MB Flash or more, I can't use this idea using BuildRoot OpenWRT because all devices with 64MB Flash not has gives me information how to prepare Device Tree **mt7620a.dts** what concret driver is compatybile and etc.

Actualy device tree inode support flash size with 16MB it is look as below

```
palmbus@10000000 {
        spi@b00 {
            status = "okay";

            m25p80@0 {
                #address-cells = <1>;
                #size-cells = <1>;
                compatible = "en25q64";
                reg = <0 0>;
                linux,modalias = "m25p80", "en25q64";
                spi-max-frequency = <10000000>;

                partition@0 {
                    label = "u-boot";
                    reg = <0x0 0x30000>;
                    read-only;
                };

                partition@30000 {
                    label = "u-boot-env";
                    reg = <0x30000 0x10000>;
                    read-only;
                };

                factory: partition@40000 {
                    label = "factory";
                    reg = <0x40000 0x10000>;
                    read-only;
                };

                partition@50000 {
                    label = "firmware";
                    reg = <0x50000 0xfb0000>;
                };
            };


        };
```

As You see  was used **m25p80**

Comment: I didn't get what is wrong with m25p80 driver so far?

Comment: You traing me tell,  driver m25p80 will be able support MT25QL512AB ? If Yes, What I will must add to code ? Problably certian structure, because I do not saw anything in code. Can You explain something more ?

Comment: Might be this helps https://community.freescale.com/thread/364435

Comment: I found something similar, but that what You me showed is also may be using. thx

Answer (score 0):

I have checked m25p80.c there is no support for your spi flash in it.
so I suggest you either add support manualy your self or take a look at this driver I came across
[ralink_spi.c](https://github.com/mqmaker/linux/blob/master/drivers/mtd/ralink/ralink_spi.c)
let me know about your results.
I dont have that chip otherwise I would have tried it myself.
and resently there is added support for 32MB+ flash chips like m25q256fv etc.

Let me know